# What Causes (and How to Reproduce) a Tikz Pencildraw Anomaly

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\definecolor{darklavender}{rgb}{0.45, 0.31, 0.59}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=darklavender!40,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \textbf{``.'' \vskip 6pt \hfill \textit{---}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces the box:

[image]

And it produces that box *most* of the time; but every once in a while, it produces something different---

[image]

This phenomenon is rare (perhaps once every one or two hundred times, I've noticed), but it continually seems to occur.

QUESTION 1: Can anyone explain why this is happening?

QUESTION 2: I kind of like this typographical (8-sided if you count carefully) anomaly. How may I reproduce this figure at will?

Removing the pencildraw-related commands does not quite do it:

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}}, fill=darklavender!40,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \textbf{``.'' \vskip 6pt \hfill \textit{---}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

It basically gives a rectangular shape:

[image]

Comment: You most likely have some `\tikzset`s floating around which cause this "anomaly". And for the last one you need to add `rounded corners`.